# Passing @states and props to popup model

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, coffeescript, semantic-ui

i am using react js for my views! i am doing a pop up to show some details of the data that is keyed in by the user and the pop up will show upon clicking submit button!
how will i pass the job state to a popup on clicking submit button ?
the pop up code is! (using coffee script)

```js
    @Jobs.TipIncrease = React.createClass
       displayName: "TipIncrease"

       componentDidMount: ->
    $(".ui.modal").modal
      # detachable: false
      onApprove: =>
        data =
          meet_at_car: false
        @disableButtonShowSpinner()
        @props.saveJobValues(data, @props.handleSubmit)
      onDeny: =>
        data = 
          meet_at_car: false
        @disableButtonShowSpinner()
        @props.saveJobValues(@props.handleSubmit)

  disableButtonShowSpinner: ->
    $("#submit-done").addClass('hide')
    $("#submit-button").addClass('disabled').css("padding", "1.5em")
    $("#submit-spinner").removeClass('hide')

  render: ->
    job = @props.job
    # @setState jobs: jobs
    # CSS & Stylings
    modalStyle =
      maxWidth: "33%"
      marginLeft: "-275px"
    # Render
    React.DOM.div
      className: "ui modal"
      # style: modalStyle
      React.DOM.div
        className: "header"
        "Increase Tip peeps"

      # Gogetter Tips
      React.DOM.div
        className: "row"
        # style: borderBottom
        React.DOM.div
          className: "sixteen wide column"
          className: "content"
          React.createElement Jobs.TipBox,
            # poster_tip: job.poster_tip
            saveJobValues: @props.saveJobValues

      React.DOM.div
        className: "actions"
        React.DOM.div
          className: "ui red cancel inverted medium button"
          style: padding: "9px 50px 7px 17px"
          React.DOM.i
            className: "remove icon"
            "Later"
        React.DOM.div
          className: "ui green ok inverted medium button"
          style: padding: "9px 60px 7px 17px"
          React.DOM.i
            className: "checkmark icon"
            "Submit"
```

Here ( poster_tip: job.poster_tip ) poster tip is undefined. thats the problem i am facing because the state is not passing! And i am showing it like!

```
          # Done button
      React.DOM.div
        className: "sixteen wide column"
        React.createElement Jobs.Button.DoneModal
      # TipIncrease at Car Modal
      React.DOM.div
        className: "sixteen wide column"
        React.createElement Jobs.TipIncrease,
          saveJobValues: @props.saveJobValues
          handleSubmit: @props.handleSubmit
```

the popup works fine but it is not taking the states of the job created!

```js
@Jobs.Button.DoneModal = React.createClass
  displayName: "Button-DoneModal"

  showModal: ->
    # $(".ui.small.modal").modal("show")
    $(".ui.modal").modal("show")
    $('.ui.dimmer.modals').appendTo('.ui.fluid.container.pushable');

  render: ->
    # CSS & Stylings
    buttonStyle =
      backgroundColor: "#00b4ad"
      color: "white"
      borderRadius: "2em"
      width: "100%"
      padding: "1em"
      fontSize: "18px"
      margin: "1em auto"

    # Render
    React.DOM.button
      type: "button"
      className: "ui button"
      id: "submit-button"
      onClick: @showModal
      style: buttonStyle
      React.DOM.span
        id: "submit-done"
        "DONE"
      React.DOM.div
        className: "ui small hide active loader"
        id: "submit-spinner"
```

how will i pass the states ? 
the error is:

```
( Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within render). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state. )
```

Comment: Please update the indentation in the code you pasted, which is important in coffeescript; otherwise it's hard to read the code logic.

Comment: @ArieShaw its almost correct! its super hard to indent it properly here! i am getting error! ( Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state. )

Comment: i want to get the current "tip" state and show it into the model but everytime i can job.tip its undefined!

Comment: paste the code as it is to the textarea on SO, select the code block, and click the `{}` button above the textarea. This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

When you create `Jobs.TipIncrease`, you're using:

```
React.createElement Jobs.TipIncrease,
  saveJobValues: @props.saveJobValues
  handleSubmit: @props.handleSubmit
```

so there will only be two properties available in the `Jobs.TipIncrease` body: `saveJobValues` and `handleSubmit`. Referencing `@props.jobs` results in `undefined`. You need to add an entry `jobs: your_jobs` here.

I didn't see `setState` call in your code pasted, there must be other place where you missed.

Comment: Thats the thing i am confused about that how to/will i setStates in a model!